# Creating multicast delegate--failure

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a multicast delegate question.

This is based on some code in C# In A Nutshell Version 5.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public delegate int Transformer(int x);

class MainClass
{
    static int Square(int x) { return x * x; }
    static int Cube(int x) { return x * x * x; }

    static void Main()
    {
        Transformer t, q, multi;
        t = Square;
        q = Cube;

        multi = t + q;
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(multi(i));
    }
}
```

The output is from `Cube` alone. Why does the addition fail?

Comment: Wrong operator, you meant to use t(i) + q(i).  The C# compiler makes hay of your current code by calling Delegate.Combine().  Giving you a new delegate object that calls both targets, one after another.  The result is whatever is returned by the last target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the `Square` method runs and then the `Cube` method runs for each value.  The return value of `multi()` is the return value of last method in the invocation list, so that's why you see only the value of `Cubes`.

The addition does not faill it works as expected. You can verify this by putting a `Console.WriteLine` inside of the `Square` method.

Comment: @Ron That's almost certainly not the proper design here.  You should simply apply a collection of delegates, rather than a single delegate with multiple associated methods.